# Using parameter in constructors C#

Tags: c#, variables, parameters, constructor

I'm abit new in C#. I have some code like this:

```
namespace Example
{
    public partial class Example_Setting : Form
    {
        public Example_Setting(String somethings)
        {
        }
        private myPlace()
        {
             MessageBox.Show(somethings);
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to get value of `somethings` variable in `myPlace()`.How can I do?

Comment: Check out a concept of [class field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for you to learn a bit more about C# before? This is an extremely basic question, which should be covered really quickly in any tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

An example would be:

```
namespace Example
{
    public partial class Example_Setting : Form
    {
        string somethings; // <-- declare a variable in the class
        public Example_Setting(String somethings)
        {
              this.somethings = somethings; // save param to variable
        }
        private myPlace()
        {
             MessageBox.Show(somethings); // now data is here for use
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may want to make the usage in `myPlace` use the `this.somethings` to remove any potential confusion

Comment: @Blorg - I know I took a fair few liberties with your post - putting in the comments, and a description and formatting your code. Hope you dont mind.

Comment: It's my first actual answer on this site, so I appreciate the help. I was struggling just to format it like a code snippet :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use below code.Declaring the other variable and assign it into constructore and then you can use it in whole class.

```
  public partial class Example_Setting : Form
 {
   public string some;
    public Example_Setting(String somethings)
    {
       this.some = something;
    }
    private myPlace()
    {
         MessageBox.Show(this.some);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have already demonstrated an example.  I just want to point out *why* you can't access *somethings* from *myPlace*.

In the example provided in your question, *somethings* is scoped [locally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) to the constructor.  That is, once the constructor has completed, *somethings* is no longer available to reference and use.  In the examples others have provided, they scope *somethings* to the class, and then assign a the value provided in the constructor parameter.  Since *somethings* is scoped to the class, your other methods (and properties) can access it.  Note that if you use public, others outside of the class can use it as well.  Best practice though is to keep it private and if you need public access, to use a property.